# Additive Exact Functors Commute with Homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $R$ and $A$ be rings, and let $\mathscr M_R$ and $\mathscr M_A$ be the categories of $R$ and $A$ modules respectively. Let $\mathrm T:$$\mathscr M_R$ $\to $$\mathscr A_R$ be an exact, additive, covariant functor. I want to prove that $\mathrm T$ commutes with homology, i.e., $H_i(\mathrm TM_\bullet)\cong\mathrm T(H_i(M_\bullet))$ for every complex $M_\bullet$, where $H_i$ is the ith homology.

Can someone teach me how to prove this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is even  a result for contravariant  functors:

In page 93 of the book "*AN INTRODUCTION TO HOMOLOGICAL ALGEBRA*" BY *D.G.NORTHCOTT* you can see:

> Theorem 1. Let T(A) be an additive exact functor of  a single variable 
>   module and let X be a complex. Then  if T is covariant in A, we have, 
>   for each n a canonical isomorphism
>   $$H_n(T(X))\cong T(H_n(X)).$$
>   While if T is contravariant in A, this must replaced by an isomorphism 
>   $$H_n(T(X))\cong T(H^n(X)).$$
>   In either case, the isomorphism  determines a natural equivalence between 
>   the two sides regarded as functors of X.

*If this is not helpful, let me know.*